# start.spring.io does not have Gradle version

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, build.gradle

I tried to use start.spring.io to create a new Java Gradle project. But today, I found out that there are only two Gradle options - Groovy and Kotlin. I don't see any Gradle for Java.

I created a Java Gradle-Groovy project, but the Spring Boot dependency cannot be imported.

I tried to use start.spring.io to create a brand new Gradle project in Java. I expect to have the Spring Boot dependencies loaded. But they are not loaded.

Answer (score 1):

There's no Project option for Java because Gradle build scripts are not written in Java... only in Groovy or Kotlin. To select the language your application is built in, you should be looking at Language, not Project.

Comment: Yes. I select Gradle-Groovy and then select language = Java. When I unzip the project and open it, Spring Boot dependencies cannot be loaded to the project. Before last evening, there was two options: Gradle and Maven. I could open the project without any problem. But things change since last evening when there are three options : Gradle-Groovy, Gradle-Koltin and Maven.

Comment: Ok, then you're going to have to explain your problem a lot clearer then, because I have no idea what you're asking. The Spring Initializr site looks perfectly normal to me... if I generate a project with the default options (Gradle-Groovy build, Java language, etc), then I get a normal-looking project with a build.gradle file with the usual Spring dependencies and plugin...